# How does one configure a proxy upstream of browsermob on osx?

Tags: python, macos, proxy, browsermob

I'm looking to configure an upstream proxy for browsermob, preferably programmatically from within a python or shell script.

It doesn't look like the python bindings for browsermob include an upstream-proxy configuration command or method. Is there another method I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python bindings do actually allow you to configure an upstream proxy. When creating a proxy using `create_proxy`, you can set the value of `httpProxy` to the IP address and port of the upstream proxy (see the [`params` parameter on create_proxy](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py/blob/master/browsermobproxy/server.py#L30) for details).